# Saving tensors to file for reload

Tags: tensorflow, save, reload, tensor

I am processing some data from the UNSW_NB15 dataset using tensorflow and python. I want to save the processed data so that it can be reloaded at any time. This seems to be a more efficient method. What is the best and most effective way to do this?

I have not tried anything as yet. But I am wondering if there is a way to do it with a simple load statement that will not require me to sort out datatypes of columns. I am using tensorflow 2.7

Comment: Check out tf.io.write_tensor() and tf.io.read_tensor() functions.

Comment: I can not find these functions in the TensorFlow documentation. I am getting write_file and read_file but these are not working as expected. I created a function to save using write_file but this requires that I serialize the tensor which presents issues for me when I am loading it back in.

Comment: Are you using tf.data.Dataset to read in data from UNSW_NB15?

Comment: No. I am loading the data as a pandas dataframe then converting to a tensor using tf.constant (df).